# JBoss 5.0 Application unable to start/ Error in accepting files from classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jboss

I know JBoss 5 is pretty old version. But it is being used in my project for a long time, so I too have to use it as it is.

I am trying to deploy my application on JBoss but I am getting below error.
Please help me in resolving the issue.

**Console LOG**

```
22:38:21,245 ERROR [[/ProjectName]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Action.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Action.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:312)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:144)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Action.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 70 more
22:38:21,382 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
22:38:21,383 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/ProjectName] startup failed due to previous errors
22:38:21,383 INFO  [[/ProjectName]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22:38:21,442 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/ProjectName state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/JBoss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/tmp/5c4o132-yqk8xx-j0gxr24a-1-j0gxrjj4-9n/ProjectName.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:333)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:144)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
22:38:21,450 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/C:/JBoss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/ProjectName.war/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/JBoss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/tmp/5c4o132-yqk8xx-j0gxr24a-1-j0gxrjj4-9n/ProjectName.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:333)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:144)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
22:38:21,598 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console
22:38:21,713 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/C:/JBoss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/ProjectName.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/JBoss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/tmp/5c4o132-yqk8xx-j0gxr24a-1-j0gxrjj4-9n/ProjectName.war/ deployment failed

22:38:21,725 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
22:38:21,748 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
22:38:21,755 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.0.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_1_GA date=200902231221)] Started in 35s:679ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:
I was using Eclipse Neon with Java 8 and the project was build on Java 6.
After downgrading Java to java 6. it worked.

Thanks...